# PTIJ: What is the inyan of the Konami code in Uncle Moishy's song?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The [Konami code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code), represented as ↑↑↓↓← → ← →BA is clearly referenced in Uncle Moishy's famous song [Hashem is Here Hashem is There](http://www.jyrics.com/lyrics/hashem-is-here/) which asserts that Hashem is "located" in the following places

> Up, up, down, down,
> Right, left, and all around!

I would like to understand the inyan of this remez

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Just for the record, Uncle Moishy did not write the song. It's an old Chabad song (as we know, CHBD is chock full of mystical secrets and video miracles.)

Answer (score 14):

It is a kabalistic unification for Kol Nidrei. During Kol Nidrei, when the chazan recites the Konam vow:

> כָּל נִדְרֵי. וֶאֱסָרֵי. וּשְׁבוּעֵי. וַחֲרָמֵי. **וְקוֹנָמֵי.** וְקִנּוּסֵי. וְכִנּוּיֵי.

One uses the Konami code to, in part, connect the court on high and the court down here. Along with the One Who Is Everywhere, the congregation and the sinners.

> עַל דַּעַת הַמָּקוֹם וְעַל דַּעַת הַקָּהָל בִּישִׁיבָה שֶׁל מַעְלָה וּבִישִׁיבָה שֶׁל מַטָּה, אָנוּ מַתִּירִין לְהִתְפַּלֵּל עִם הָעֲבַרְיָנִים.

Answer (score 8):

Clearly the inyan of this remez is to remind us that in order to prevent sin which would cause our "Doom" we must recall that "[God's mode](https://www.looper.com/11477/classic-gaming-cheat-codes-well-never-forget/)" is everywhere. Keeping that in mind will be the equivalent of 99 lives.